# On a certain radical of the formal power series ring $K[[X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{\infty}]]$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, galois-representations, nonnoetherian

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p > 2$ and $A_{\infty} \colon= K[[X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{\infty}]]$ be an infinitely-many-variable formal power series ring over $K$ (the symbol $X_{\infty}$ is to distinguish $A_{\infty}$ from other similar ones. E.g., $A_{\infty}$ is complete and contains the formal summation $X_1 + X_2 +\ldots\,$).

We shall define the closed ideal $I$ of $A_{\infty}$ as follows$\colon$
\begin{equation*}
I \colon= (X_1^p, X_2^{p^2}, \ldots, X_i^{p^i}, \ldots),
\end{equation*} 
where $I$ being closed implies that any infinite summation $a_1 X_1^p + a_2 X_2^{p^2} + \ldots + a_i X_i^{p^i} + \ldots \in I$ for $a_1, a_2,\ldots \in A_{\infty}$. For the above defined ideal $I$, its radical is defined as $\sqrt{I} \colon= \{x \in A_{\infty} \,|\, x^n \in I \,for~^{\exists} n > 0~{\mathrm{with}}~n~{\mathrm{being~an~integer}}\}$.

### Question(Nilradical lemma). Is $\sqrt{I}$ a prime ideal of $A_{\infty}$?

I am *not* sure whether the following proof of the question is correct or not. Any comment is helpful on the following $``$proof$"$$\colon$

Proof. We shall substitute each parameter $X_n$ with $X_n^{1/p^n}$ and then we see that the ideal $I \colon= (X_1^p, X_2^{p^2}, \ldots, X_i^{p^i}, \ldots)$ at issue will turn out to be the following closed ideal $J$ of $K[[X_1^{1/p}, X_2^{1/p^2},\ldots,X_{\infty}^{1/p^{\infty}}]]$$\colon$ 
$$
J \colon= (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_i, \ldots).
$$

So suppose that two elements $\alpha, \beta \in K[[X_1^{1/p}, X_2^{1/p^2},\ldots,X_{\infty}^{1/p^{\infty}}]]$ satisfy the condition that $\alpha \notin \sqrt{J}$, and $\beta \notin \sqrt{J}$. Then we have to show that $\alpha \beta \notin \sqrt{J}$ in the ring $K[[X_1^{1/p}, X_2^{1/p^2}, \ldots, X_{\infty}^{1/p^{\infty}}]]$. We shall introduce a new notion.

Definition($\epsilon$-monomials). For a positive number $\epsilon > 0$, the $\epsilon$-monomial $X_{i_1}^{e_{i_1}} \cdots X_{i_n}^{e_{i_n}}$ of $K[[X_1^{1/p}, X_2^{1/p^2}, \ldots, X_{\infty}^{1/p^{\infty}}]]$ is defined to satisfy the following condition$\colon$ 
\begin{equation*}
{\mathrm{There~ exists~least~index~}} e_{i_k} ~{\mathrm{such~that}}~e_{i_k} = \epsilon.
\end{equation*}
That is, at least one index $e_{i_k}$ is equal to $\epsilon$, and the others possess indices equal to or smaller than $\epsilon$.

Suppose $\alpha \notin \sqrt{J}$. Then for an arbitrarily small number $\delta$, there always exists some nonzero $\epsilon$-monomial contained in $\alpha$ such that $\epsilon < \delta$. This is understood by the observation that for an $\epsilon$-monomial $(X_{i_1}^{e_{i_1}} \cdots X_{i_n}^{e_{i_n}})^{p^M}$ to belong to the radical $\sqrt{J}$ of $J$, $M$ necessarily requires $p^M \geq 1/\epsilon$, which tends to be $\infty$ when $\epsilon \to 0$. Also we are going to keep in mind that the suffix $n$ for the variable $X_n$ must satisfy $n \geq -{\mathrm{log}}_p (\epsilon)$ when $X_n$ is a constituent of $\epsilon$-monomial.

For any $\epsilon$, we can choose all $\epsilon$-monomials from $\alpha$ and define $P_{\epsilon}(\alpha)$ as the summation of them. Running over the range $0 < \epsilon < 1$, the following element $\widetilde{\alpha}$ is associated to $\alpha$$\colon$
$$
\widetilde{\alpha} \colon= \underset{0 < \epsilon < 1}{\Sigma} P_{\epsilon}(\alpha).
$$
We know that there exists arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ such that $P_{\epsilon}(\alpha)$ is nonzero because $\alpha \notin \sqrt{J}$. We recall that the suffix $n$ tends to infinity as $\epsilon \to 0$ when $X_n$ appears in $P_{\epsilon}(\alpha)$.

Now, we shall begin to successfully collect certain monomials in $\widetilde{\alpha}$ in descending orders. We begin with $X_1$ and try to find the smallest index $0 < e_1$ such that $X_1^{e_1}$ appears in $\widetilde{\alpha}$. Then we shall choose those monomials containing $X_1^{e_1}$ in $\widetilde{\alpha}$ and write the summation of them as $a_1X_1^{e_1}$. Next we discard all monomials which contain $X_i^{\epsilon}$ such that $\epsilon > e_1$ for some $i \geq 1$. Among the rest we go on to find the minimal index $e_2$ such that $X_2^{e_2}$ appears therein and if such $e_2$ does not exist, we set $e_2 \colon= -\infty$, hence zero. We gather all those monomials containing $X_2^{e_2}$ and write the summation of them $a_2X_2^{e_2}$. We shall repeat this process to eventually reach the following element$\colon$
$$
\epsilon(\alpha) = \underset{1 \leq i}{\Sigma} a_iX_i^{e_i}.
$$

Now, we are ready to prove the theorem. We rewrite $\epsilon(\alpha)$ as follows$\colon$ 
\begin{equation*}
\epsilon({\alpha}) = a_1X_1^{e_1} + a_2X_2^{e_2} + \ldots + a_nX_n^{e_n} + \ldots + a_{\infty}X_{\infty}^{e_{\infty}}.
\end{equation*} 
As a very important fact, $X_1$ never appears in $a_2, a_3, \ldots$, and $X_i$ never appears in $a_j$ for $j > i$ as well, which follows from the fact that each chosen monomial $a_jX_{j}^{e_j}$ is among those which do not contain $X_i$ by the above process. In the similar manner for $\beta \notin \sqrt{J}$, we associate $\epsilon({\beta})$ as follows$\colon$
\begin{equation*}
\epsilon({\beta}) = b_1X_1^{e_1'} + b_2X_2^{e_2'} + \ldots + b_nX_n^{e_n'} + \ldots + b_{\infty}X_{\infty}^{e_{\infty}'}.
\end{equation*}
If we can prove that there exists arbitrarily-small-indexed monomial in the product $\epsilon({\alpha})\epsilon({\beta})$, we win, for such monomial also survives in $\alpha \beta$. However, we will immediately realise that all equalities $e_i = e_i'$ must hold for $i \gg 0$ ; otherwise we have $e_i < e_i'$, say, and the product $a_i X_i^{e_i} b_j X_j^{e_j'}$ with any $j > i$, which can be a nonzero arbitrarily-small-indexed monomial, will survive ($a_ib_j$ is not zero and $a_ib_j$ comprises $\epsilon$-monomials such that $\epsilon \leq \delta$ for any small $\delta > 0$ when $i, j \to \infty$). Therefore without loss of generality we may suppose that $e_i = e_i'$ for all $i \geq 1$ from the beginning and the product turns out as follows$\colon$
\begin{equation}\label{AS}
\epsilon({\alpha})\epsilon({\beta}) = (a_1X_1^{e_1} + a_2X_2^{e_2} + \ldots + a_{\infty}X_{\infty}^{e_{\infty}})
(b_1X_1^{e_1} + b_2X_2^{e_2} + \ldots + b_{\infty}X_{\infty}^{e_{\infty}}).
\end{equation}
Suppose that the element $a_iX_i^{e_i} b_jX_j^{e_j} + a_jX_j^{e_j} b_iX_i^{e_i}$, or equally $(a_ib_j + a_jb_i)X_i^{e_i}X_j^{e_j}$ remained nonzero for any large pair $j > i \gg 0$. Then the similar argument would lead to the fact that $\epsilon({\alpha}) \epsilon({\beta})$ cannot belong to $\sqrt{J}$, hence $\alpha \beta \notin \sqrt{J}$ as well. Thus we conclude that $a_ib_j + a_jb_i = 0$ for $j>i \gg 0$. Without loss of generality, we may suppose the following equality from the beginning$\colon$
$$
(\lozenge) \quad a_ib_j + a_jb_i = 0 \quad {\mathrm{for~ any~ pair}}~ j > i > 0. 
$$
From this, we obtain the following equality for an arbitrary $i > 0$$\colon$
$$
(\epsilon({\alpha}) - a_iX_i^{e_i})b_iX_i^{e_i} + (\epsilon({\beta}) - b_iX_i^{e_i})a_iX_i^{e_i} = 0. 
$$
Or we have 
$$
(\epsilon({\alpha}) - a_iX_i^{e_i})b_iX_i^{e_i} = -(\epsilon({\beta}) - b_iX_i^{e_i})a_iX_i^{e_i}. 
$$
Because $K[[X_1^{1/p}, X_2^{1/p^2}, \ldots, X_{\infty}^{1/p^{\infty}}]]$ is a UFD by Nishimura, if we have any common prime divisor for $\epsilon({\alpha})$ and $a_iX_i^{\epsilon_i}$ it must be a prime divisor of $\epsilon({\alpha})$, hence only a finitely many possibilities. Let us choose one such prime divisor ${\frak p} = (u_{\frak p})$, where $u_{\frak p}$ is the generator of ${\frak p}$. We may suppose that $u_{\frak p}$ contains a parameter $X_m^{\gamma}$, say, as a constituent of its formal power series presentation. On the other hand, $a_iX_i^{e_i}$ will not contain any power of the variable $X_m$ for sufficiently large $i \gg 0$, for $a_i$ ceases to contain smaller suffices $m$, i.e. $X_m$'s when $i \to \infty$ by the above recipe. Therefore except finitely many $a_iX_i^{e_i}$'s, $(\widetilde{\alpha} - a_iX_i^{e_i})$ and $a_iX_i^{e_i}$ are coprime to each other. The same reasoning shows that $(\epsilon({\beta}) - b_iX_i^{e_i})$ and $b_iX_i^{e_i}$ are copime to each other except for finitely many $b_iX_i^{e_i}$'s. Thus we conclude that $b_i = a_iu_i$ with some unit $u_i$ for $i \gg 0$.

Finally by substituting this equality in $(\lozenge)$, we obtain $a_ia_ju_j + a_ja_iu_i = 0$, hence $u_j + u_i = 0$ for $j > i \gg 0$. This, however, provides us with the information that for $k > j > i \gg 0$ we have the equalities $u_k + u_j = 0$, $u_k + u_i = 0$, and $u_j + u_i = 0$, which leads to the equality $2u_k = 0$, hence $u_k = 0$, $u_i = u_j = 0$ for $i \gg 1$ as well due to the fact of ${\mathrm{ch}}(K) > 2$. This is a contradiction. Q.E.D.

Comment: Obviously, $\sqrt{I}=J$ (prime). For, $I \subseteq J$, hence $\sqrt{I}\subseteq \sqrt{J}=J$. Conversly, each generator $X_i$ of $J$ is in $\sqrt{I}$. Hence $J \subseteq \sqrt{I}$.

Comment: Not correct. All $X_i$' are *NOT* generators of $J$. This is because $J$ is *NOT* closed ideal. For example, the infinite summation $X_1 + X_2 + ... $ does *NOT* belong to $J$. $A_{\infty}$ is *NOT* equal to the inductive limit of $K[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]]$ over all $n \geq 1$. $J$ has continuously cardinal generators if any. The question is more subtle and far from obvious because of the hugeness of $A_{\infty}$.

Comment: Well, the notation $I \colon= (X_1^p, X_2^{p^2}, \ldots, X_i^{p^i}, \ldots)$ usually means that $I$ is generated by the $X_i^{p^i}$ (and similar for $J$). If you mean something diferent for $I$, you should define it accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry but $I$ is *closed* in the sense we can sum infinitely many variables $X_1,\ldots$. Thanks.